# how to implement toggle behavior using Imageview, no UIButton

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uibutton, uiswitch

I have to implement a toggle like behavior between to differentiate between two states, client doesn't want UIbuttons because he has his own png's and wants them to be used. 
so I need to have to UIImageViews next to each other.
I am talking about UIImageviews because the toggle behavior the client wants should be a sliding one, as in the user has two options in the control ( like on / off ) he slides the UI from on to off, or off to on, I was given 4 png's: 2 for the on state ( normal and depressed ) and 2 for the off state ( Normal and depressed ) .

I also looked into UISwitch, but again to customize it the way I want to seemed cumbersome, any ideas?

Comment: why not set these pngs on UIButtons?

Comment: because the toggle behavior he wants should be a sliding one, as in the user has two options in the control ( like on / off ) he slides the UI from on to off, or off to on, I was given 4 png's: 2 for the on state ( normal and depressed ) and 2 for the off state ( Normal and depressed ) .

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what your client wants this way:

```
   UIButton *nameOfButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
   [nameOfButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:nameOfYourClientsPNGFiles] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   [nameOfButton addTarget:self action:@selector(actionForButton) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   [self.view addSubview:nameOfButton];
```

//Note that all the words are to be replaced with what your methods and pointers are.

Also if your clients PNG files are not the traditional square images I strongly recommend looking into this Custom Class:-)

[OBShapedButton](https://github.com/ole/OBShapedButton)

It sorts out the problem that the user can only tab and click the shape of the image.